# Apache error.log Invalid command 'RewriteEngine', perhaps misspelled or defined by a module not included in the server configuration

Tags: php, apache, mod-rewrite

Was getting a `500 Internal Server Error` checked the Apache log found this error:

```
Invalid command 'RewriteEngine', perhaps misspelled or defined by a module not included in the server configuration
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't forget to Enable module rewrite :-)

```
a2enmod rewrite
systemctl restart apache2
```